# What is the cleanest way to pass a formGroup to a mat-step?

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to use the [stepper component](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#using-a-single-form) from angular-material together with reactive forms. The problem is that I don't what is the best way (from an architectural point of view) to allow each `mat-step` to access a `formGroup`.

Looking at the two examples below, it seems that the easiest way is to create `formGroup1` and `formGroup2` outside of the stepper (example 1). My issue with this approach is that inside each `<form>` I want to have only one custom component that contains its one `formGroup` and I don't think the container of the stepper should know about the `formGroups`. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
<parent that declares formGroup1>
    <mat-vertical-stepper linear>
      <mat-step [stepControl]="formGroup1">
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup1">
            <component that uses formGroup1></component>
        </form>
      </mat-step>
    <<mat-vertical-stepper>
</parent>

<parent oblivious to formGroup2>
    <mat-vertical-stepper linear>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="formGroup2">
            <form [formGroup]="formGroup2">
                <component declaring formGroup2></component>
            </form>
         </mat-step>
    </mat-vertical-stepper>
</parent>
```

Solutions that I have considered:

- Declare all formGroups in the parent of the stepper and propagate them to children (downside: seems like too much responsibility on parent and more difficult to understand the code)
- Declare each formGroup inside child component and emit using `@Output()` to parent. Use `FormArray` inside parent so that it's ignorant to the child logic (downside: need to use an index/identifier to make sure the correct form is on the correct position)
- Use a single form in the parent for the whole stepper

I'd like to know if there's one good solution for this. It feels like I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: why not declare in main the whole formGroup, and use `<form [formGroup]="myForm.get('group1')">` in each step?, see a example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaee8g?file=app/stepper-optional-example.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in our application and I went with the @Output() approach. Don't know if it is the best, but it was working fine.

Parent Component html

```
<mat-step
        [stepControl]="form1"
        label="Step1"
        [completed]="form1?.valid">
      <app-step-one [(form)]="form1"></app-step-one>
    </mat-step>
```

Parent Component

```
form1: FormGroup;
```

Child Component html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
.....
</form>
```

Child Component ~ You could inherit that for every step from a parent class

```
  _form: FormGroup;

  @Input()
  get form() {
    return this._form;
  }

  @Output()
  formChange = new EventEmitter();
  set form(value) {
    this._form = value;
    this.formChange.emit(this._form);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      item: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }
```